# Conditional Generic Types in TypeScript use Discriminated Union

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typechecking

I have two interfaces in my code that I want to select one type between these two.

Here is the code for the interfaces:

```
interface createUserToSiteMutateUseStates {
  setStateId: (value: React.SetStateAction<string | null | undefined>) => void;
  StateId: string | null | undefined;
  setCityId: (value: React.SetStateAction<string | null | undefined>) => void;
}

interface updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariablesUseState {
  setStateSelected: (
    value: React.SetStateAction<SelectorOptions[] | undefined | null>
  ) => void;
}
```

I created a type to recognition of true interface:

```
type whichType<T> = T extends "createUserToSiteMutate"
  ? createUserToSiteMutateUseStates
  : T extends "updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariables"
  ? updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariablesUseState
  : null;
```

And finally I used the `whichType`:

```
export interface Props {
  type:
    | "createUserToSiteMutate"
    | "createUnitVariables"
    | "updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariables";
  useStateProps?: whichType<type>;
}
```

But when I use `Props`, I get this error:

```
const handleChange = (option: SelectorOptions) => {
      switch (type) {
        case "createUserToSiteMutate":
          useStateProps!.setCityId && useStateProps!.setCityId(null);
          useStateProps!.setUniversityId &&
            useStateProps!.setUniversityId(null);
          useStateProps!.setOrganizationId &&
            useStateProps!.setOrganizationId(null);
          useStateProps!.setUnitId && useStateProps!.setUnitId(null);
          useStateProps!.setStateId && useStateProps!.setStateId(option.value);
        default:
          break;
      }
    };
```

> Property 'setCityId' does not exist on type 'createUserToSiteMutateUseStates | updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariablesUseState'.
>
> Property 'setCityId' does not exist on type 'updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariablesUseState'.ts(2339)

How can I fix this error? Is a problem in `whichType`?

Comment: there is no setCityId in updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariablesUseState but I get this error.

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to be a true [mcve] as described in [ask].  Right now there are lots of errors that seem to be unrelated to your question. If someone drops the code into a standalone IDE, they should be able to reproduce your specific issue without having to spend time trying to fix or selectively ignore other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional type is generic and requires a type parameter, but you haven't given it one inside your `Props` interface.  The property `useStateProps?: whichType<type>` doesn't compile because `type` is not a type; it seems to be the key name of another property.  In order for that to work you need `Props` to itself be generic.

Instead of using generics or conditional types I'd suggest that you make `Props` a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) to get the desired behavior.  Here's one way to do it that seems similar to your current setup:

```
interface TypeMap {
    createUserToSiteMutate: CreateUserToSiteMutateUseStates,
    updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariables: UpdateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariablesUseState,
    createUnitVariables: null
}

type Props = { [K in keyof TypeMap]: {
    type: K,
    useStateProps?: TypeMap[K];
} }[keyof TypeMap];
```

If you inspect that, `Props` is equivalent to:

```
type Props = {
    type: "createUserToSiteMutate";
    useStateProps?: CreateUserToSiteMutateUseStates | undefined;
} | {
    type: "updateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariables";
    useStateProps?: UpdateStoreSpatialCommitmentsVariablesUseState | undefined;
} | {
    type: "createUnitVariables";
    useStateProps?: null | undefined;
}
```

So now the `Props` type has a `type` *discriminant* property which can be used to narrow the type to one of the three union members if you switch on it.  Note that you have to keep the properties in a single `Props` object to do this; you can't copy them to other variables and maintain the correlation between `props` and `useStateProps`.  So `if (props.type === "...") { props.useStateProps... } else ...` will work, but `const type = props.type; const useStateProps = props.useStateProps; if (type == "...") { useStateProps... } else ..." will not.

So this would be how you'd write it:

```
declare const props: Props;

const handleChange = (option: SelectorOptions) => {
    switch (props.type) {
        case "createUserToSiteMutate":
            props.useStateProps!.setCityId && props.useStateProps!.setCityId(null);
            props.useStateProps!.setStateId && props.useStateProps!.setStateId(option.value);
        default:
            break;
    }
};
```

You can see that it compiles without error now.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-xtcZcAERkeFwaQ9DgMBFwrOAXyXK0mEQmR4BsMYhF8AjDB4FcilfdUdCVIUxAkFpUDNFZL0yCxolwKwXlQ19UCqa8sAWFjeUUXA0B4AAiAdEkjAMYziepxK0MVhMUbilyqR8E0CTDUAAQiqLJ7hnAo4AAMlMlC0I0p9tLQ-TDMeAoiiNOYrRUlS1N4zTfh0+zZXqEzzMsnjrK09hfIM-y8nyCj6OkKoJQEtz3MhZABhgJS+3cpRmQCHdksUFEXBoIA)